# Assigning input to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying a simple code but I'm stuck. I want to ask a question to the user and store the answer to an input, and then write it on a file.
Here's the code :

```
input = open("Wishes.txt", "w")
wish = input("What do you wish ?")   
input.write(wish)
print("Thank you")
```

I get this error : TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

I'm sure it is really easy but I'm a beginner so I don't know where to find a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't create a variable called `input`. `input` is that useful function you're trying to call.

Comment: Have you consulted any tutorial or instructional materials of any kind?

Comment: Well thank you, I saw someone naming this variable input and I copied that. Sorry for the inconveniance, it's working now

Answer (score 1):

You have hidden the function name `input` by creating a variable called `input`. Simply rename the variable.

Also you probably want to append to the file instead of overwriting the whole thing. And you should be using `with` to properly handle an external resource.

```
wish = input("What do you wish ?")
with open("Wishes.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write(wish + "\n")
print("Thank you")
```

Comment: and maybe write a newline

Comment: @alani good point

Comment: Thank you for the advice ! What is a newline ?

Comment: @Thomas a new-line or a line-break signals when to put content on the next line. The character for that in a string is `"\n"`